# linear regression with feature normalization matlab code

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression, normalization

I did it two ways, why is the first way(starting on line with mu=mean(X) not working?  what's the difference?

```
 function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)
    %FEATURENORMALIZE Normalizes the features in X 
    %   FEATURENORMALIZE(X) returns a normalized version of X where
    %   the mean value of each feature is 0 and the standard deviation
    %   is 1. This is often a good preprocessing step to do when
    %   working with learning algorithms.

    % You need to set these values correctly
    X_norm = X;
    mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
    sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));

    % ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    % Instructions: First, for each feature dimension, compute the mean
    %               of the feature and subtract it from the dataset,
    %               storing the mean value in mu. Next, compute the 
    %               standard deviation of each feature and divide
    %               each feature by it's standard deviation, storing
    %               the standard deviation in sigma. 
    %
    %               Note that X is a matrix where each column is a 
    %               feature and each row is an example. You need 
    %               to perform the normalization separately for 
    %               each feature. 
    %
    % Hint: You might find the 'mean' and 'std' functions useful.
    %       

    %mu=mean(X)
    %X_norm=X-mu;
    %sigma=std(X_norm)
    %X_norm(1)=X_norm(1)/sigma(1)
    %X_norm(2)=X_norm(2)/sigma(2)



    % Calculates mean and std dev for each feature
    for i=1:size(mu,2)
        mu(1,i) = mean(X(:,i)); 
        sigma(1,i) = std(X(:,i));
        X_norm(:,i) = (X(:,i)-mu(1,i))/sigma(1,i);
    end







    % ============================================================

    end
```

Comment: your for loop is wrong, should be 
`for i = 1: size(X,2) `
cos you want to dynamically loop through the number of features in the dataset

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you try to subtract a vector from a matrix. `mean(X)` gives you a vector with the mean in the columns of X, dimension [1xC], and the X is dimension [RxC]. A way to solve this in a oneliner is

```
 X = (X-repmat(mean(X,1),size(X,1),1))./repmat(std(X,0,1),size(X,1),1)
```

Comment: `X_norm = (X_norm-mu)./sigma;` this would also work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through `X`. You can further verify the output of above code with [normalize(X)](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.normalize.html)

```
for i = 1: size(X, 2)
    mu = mean(X(:, i));
    sigma = std(X(:, i));
    X_norm(:, i) = (X(:, i) - mu) ./ sigma
end
```